# Запуск приложения, а не конкретного Activity нажатием на Notification

Tags: android, java

Сейчас Notification у меня реализован таким образом, что по нажатию он открывает главный Activity моего приложения. Мне нужно сделать его таким образом, чтобы уведомление открывало приложение как это делает диспетчер задач, т.е. открывает приложение в том состоянии на том активити на котором был свернут, а если приложение открыто, то действие не требуется. Это возможно реализовать?

Comment: На ум приходит только использование одного Activity с фрагментами внутри. То есть, если у Вас уже была открытая информация, то она и останется открытой. Наверное, нужно ещё в манифесте нужно прописать у этого Activity возможность запуск в единственном экземпляре.

Comment: Не очень изящно, учитывая что приложение уже написано)

Answer (score 3):

Есть 2 подхода:

1) В каждом активити при `onPause()` записывать в преференсы имя последнего `Activity`, соответственно в преференсах у вас всегда будет имя последней активной `Activity` и при запуске главного `Activity`, проверяя преференсы можно перенаправить на нужную

2) При запуске приложения смотреть в стек запущенных `Activity` и выцеплять свои и активировать последнюю (требуется спец. пермишен `android.permission.GET_TASKS`):

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> list=am.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
for (RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {//сканируем весь стек
if(context.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(task.baseActivity.getPackageName())) 
//blah-blah
}
```